# Pie charts with linear gradients - swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics, pie-chart, linear-gradients

I know this question has been around quite a couple of times. I tried to implement all the answers to my case but I stil cannot figure out how to do it.

I have a kind of pie chart and I would like to create gradients for every segment, for example green at the center and more red as it goes away from the center (or everything else...). But I am either facing a gradient that takes all the screen (it looks like I have not understood how clipping a context works) or I do not see anything.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let centerX = (bounds.size.width)/2
        let centerY = (bounds.size.height)/2
        let center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        let radius: (CGFloat) = min(centerX/2, centerY/2)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // A method where I configure labels
        func label(text: String, value: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {

            let labX = centerX + cos(angle) * newValue * 1.2
            let labY = centerY + sin(angle) * newValue * 1.2
            let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: labX, y: labY, width: 80, height: 40))

            ...
            addSubview(myLabel)
        }

        // Configure arc -> where I try to add gradients to my segments
        func arc(radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat) {

            var finalRadius: CGFloat = radius
            if radius == -1 {
                finalRadius = 100
                phenotypeColor = UIColor.init(red: 159/255.0, green: 193/255.0, blue: 204/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
            }
            else {
                phenotypeColor = UIColor.orange
            }

            context?.setFillColor(phenotypeColor.cgColor)
            context?.move(to: center)
            context?.addArc(center: center, radius: finalRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: edAngle, clockwise: true)
            context?.fillPath()

            // I would like to implement here a gradient layer to the newly-created arc. I tried o add a CAGradientLayer but I cannot apply it to the segment area...
        }

        // One arc
        label(text: ..., value: ..., angle: ..., color: ...)
        arc(radius: ..., startAngle: ..., endAngle: ...)

        //Another arc
        ...


    }
```

If anyone could help me...

This is just an image of what I have without any gradient:
[image]

EDIT:
I try to add those lines below without any success.

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: finalRadius, startAngle: myStartAngle, endAngle: myEndAngle, clockwise: true)
    let RectView = path.bounds
    let myView = UIView.init(frame: RectView)
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = myView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
    myView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Could anyone be able tell me how I can get a UIView from a path?

Answer (score 0):

A CAGradientLayer is what you need here.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = myView.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
myView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Where myView is a view that has a pie chart segment.

Let me know if you have any further questions and I hope you get this thing working - looks pretty cool :)

Comment: Thanks for replying! Thath is more or less what I tried before but I am not sure how I can get "myView" to be a view of one segment. I suppose it may have to involve the "clipping" context function or anything else but I cannot succeed in doing it since I use the .move, .addArc and .fillPath methods.

Answer (score 0):

> i create pie chart using echarts-for-react i need remplace colors to linear gradient

```
  const color=["red","green","blue","yellow"]
const option = {
    color: color,
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Access From',
            type: 'pie',
            radius: '50%',
            data: data,
            label: {
                fontSize: 18,
                color: 'red'
            },
            labelLayout: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                align: "center"
            },
            emphasis: {
                itemStyle: {
                    shadowBlur: 10,
                    shadowOffsetX: 10,
                    shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};    
return (
    <div style={{ height: "1000px" }}>
        <ReactEcharts
            option={option}
        />{" "}
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the .cg extension. The colors of the gradientlayer colors array should be cgColors not UiColors.

```
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: finalRadius, startAngle: myStartAngle, endAngle: myEndAngle, clockwise: true)
let RectView = path.bounds
let myView = UIView.init(frame: RectView)
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = myView.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
myView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```